# How to get the format of image with PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, image-formats

After loading an image file with PIL.Image, how can I determine whether the image file is a PNG/JPG/BMP/GIF? I understand very little about these file formats, can PIL get the `format` metadata from the file header? Or does it need to 'analyze' the data within the file?

If PIL doesn't provide such an API, is there any python library that does?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Try:

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open(filename)
print(img.format)  # 'JPEG'
```

More info

- https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.format
- https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/image-file-formats.html

Comment: I guess this attribute is just the file extension, or `None` if the image is constructed with raw data. The file extension is not always available in my case.

Comment: Please do not guess, but refer to the documentation how the file format is determined. If the PIL reads the image file it must make a choice which decoder is used and this information is exposed through format attribute.

Comment: For anyone else coming along... you can get the mimetype by doing `Image.MIME[img.format]`

Comment: is there a more lightweight version of this? for instance looking only at the header or metadata instead of opening the image?

Comment: You can use `imghdr`'s `imghdr.what(filename)` function, but it seems to be a bit buggy if extra header info is included in JPEGs (and possibly other formats).

Comment: Pillow provides `im.get_format_mimetype()` for getting image mimetype

Comment: it returns wrong value for webp, it returns jpeg instead

Comment: @TomSawyer smells like a bug, I suggest checking the issue tracker and if the issue does not exist then open a new one

Comment: @claudecomputing You can use `python-magic`. See https://pypi.org/project/python-magic/

Answer (score 0):

**Beware!** If the image you are trying to get the format from was created from a `copy()`, the format will be `None`.

From the [docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/image-file-formats.html#image-file-formats)

> Copies of the image will contain data loaded from the file, but not the file itself, meaning that it can no longer be considered to be in the original format. So if `copy()` is called on an image, or another method internally creates a copy of the image, then any methods or attributes specific to the format will no longer be present. The `fp` (file pointer) attribute will no longer be present, and the `format` attribute will be `None`.

Methods that create an implicit copy include:

- `convert()`
- `crop()`
- `remap_palette()`
- `resize()`
- `reduce()`
- `rotate()`
- `split()`
- these were all I found as of today, but others may be added

For example:

```py
img = Image.open(filename)
print(img.format)  # 'JPEG'
img2 = img.copy()
print(img.format)  # None
print(img.rotate(90, expand=True).format).  # None
```

So if you need to get the format from a copy, you need to look to the original image.