# How to get image from bytes in Python?

Tags: python, image, format, byte

I have an image (jpeg).
I get the bytes from it simply using open('img.jpg', 'rb').
And for instance I send that bytes to my friend.
So which way using Python can he get conversely operation - from bytes the image? How to decode it?

1. the way if he knows the format - JPEG for example.
2. the way if he doesn't know the format.
   Is there any ways?

Comment: Are you asking how to save the bytes to a file? Or how to display them in image form? Or something else?

Comment: I mean how to save it to file with appropriate format so friend can open it and see the image.

Comment: You mean like `open('img.jpg', 'wb').write(data)`?

Comment: oh, yes! it is what I mean. 
but it works only if I know format of data (jpg). 
And what is I don't know one? Only know that it is an image data.

Comment: To be clear, the file extension isn't necessary for the data to be a valid image. Even if you save the image with a wrong extension, like `img.bmp`, you'll still be able to open the image without any problems. There are libraries that take binary data as input and detect the file type, like the [`imghdr`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/imghdr.html) module. Or you can open the image with PIL as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32679589/how-to-get-the-format-of-image-with-pil). Or you can just send the file extension to your friend along with the image data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the PIL module. More information in answers here: [Decode image bytes data stream to JPEG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62348356/decode-image-bytes-data-stream-to-jpeg)

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO


with open('img.jpg', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()

    # Load image from BytesIO
    im = Image.open(BytesIO(data))

    # Display image
    im.show()

    # Save the image to 'result.FORMAT', using the image format
    im.save('result.{im_format}'.format(im_format=im.format))
```

Comment: Ok, and then how to put it in file with appropriate format so user can open the image?

Comment: The answer has been updated to reflect the process of saving the image with the right format.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use an external library, you can use the byte signature - which is the first few bytes of the file - to determine the image compression type.

Here are some common image formats.

```
img_types = {
    b'\xFF\xD8\xFF\xDB': 'jpg',
    b'\xFF\xD8\xFF\xE0': 'jpg',
    b'\xFF\xD8\xFF\xEE': 'jpg',
    b'\xFF\xD8\xFF\xE1': 'jpg',
    b'\x47\x49\x46\x38\x37\x61': 'gif',
    b'\x47\x49\x46\x38\x39\x61': 'gif',
    b'\x42\x4D': 'bmp',
    b'\x89\x50\x4E\x47\x0D\x0A\x1A\x0A': 'png'
}

with open('path/to/image', 'rb') as fp:
    img_bytes = fp.read()

for k, v in img_types.items():
    if img_bytes.startswith(k):
        img_type = v
        break
else:
    img_type = None
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491416/pil-convert-bytearray-to-image) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14759637/python-pil-bytes-to-image)? They are very similar with your case. Also AFAIK original format of the image does not make any difference if you convert them into bytes. So linked questions/answers should be fine. However, if they are not working, please update your question.